# test for a missing resource in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Here's a hopefully quick one for those with more Sencha Touch / Ext / JS experience than I have. How would I programmatically test for the existence of a remote resource, say an image? In other words how do I forestall an HTTP 404 before it happens and perform some default action, say swapping in a default image?

Here is what I'm currently doing (the catch(e) block is never hit):

```
albumArtArea.setTpl('<img class="cover_art" src="{iconUrl}"/>');
try {
    albumArtArea.setData(itemData);
}
catch (e) {
    // this block is never executed
    // 404 for missing album art; use the generic image
    itemData.iconUrl = "resources/images/img_music_generic.png";
    albumArtArea.setData(itemData);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this to show default image when an error occurs in loading gimage

```
function ImgError(source){
    source.src = "resources/images/img_music_generic.png";
    source.onerror = "";
    return true;
}

<img src="someimage.png" onerror="ImgError(this);" />
```

or if you are usihg jquery then

```
$('img').one('error', function() { 
       this.src = 'resources/images/img_music_generic.png';
});
```

**Reference:**

[jQuery/JavaScript to replace broken images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/92720/1237812)

Comment: I'll try something along these lines ASAP and let you know how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick (the plain JS version with onerror in the img tag).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of waiting for a 404 and then re-requesting the default image, can you let the server return the default image? You'd save a request and also simplify your client

Comment: There are no "smarts" in the server for this particular application-- at the moment I have a development Apache but in the end the app needs to run entirely off the filesystem in the browser.